# Using RAW video encoding with gstreamer & VLC

Tags: ubuntu, video, vlc

I'm streaming RAW video with gstreamer like so:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! rtpvrawpay ! udpsink host="127.0.0.1" port="5000"
```

This outputs the following caps:

```
caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)RAW, sampling=(string)YCbCr-4:2:0, depth=(string)8, width=(string)320, height=(string)240, colorimetry=(string)BT601-5, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)1103043224, timestamp-offset=(uint)1948293153, seqnum-offset=(uint)27904
```

I can view this stream with gstreamer using:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port="5000" caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)RAW, sampling=(string)YCbCr-4:2:0, depth=(string)8, width=(string)320, height=(string)240, colorimetry=(string)BT601-5, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)1103043224, timestamp-offset=(uint)1948293153, seqnum-offset=(uint)27904" ! rtpvrawdepay ! videoconvert ! queue ! xvimagesink sync=false
```

Using VLC, I've created an SDL file:

```
v=0
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
m=video 5000 RTP/AVP 96
a=rtpmap:96 RAW/90000
a=fmtp:96 media=video; clock-rate=90000; encoding-name=RAW
```

But VLC errors with:

```
core input error: no suitable demux module for `file/any:///home/.../settings.sdp'
```

How can I have VLC accept the RAW stream?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently VLC does not support raw Video via RTP, see https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=145855 (quite recent) and https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=45 (older).